# pvmove to smaller drive?

Tags: centos7, lvm, pvmove

I am running on CentOS 7, lvm, with an XFS formatted root drive. As originally set up, the server had a single large root volume that contained both the OS and the data. The data has now grown, and I would like to move it off to a separate drive. This is simple enough, but at the end of the process it will leave a fairly large root drive almost empty. As this is a VM (proxmox server), and I would like to free up the host drive space, I want to "shrink" the root drive. So far the best procedure I have come up with is the following:

1. Add a new, smaller, physical drive to the drive group
2. Use `pvmove` to move the extents from the old drive to the new drive
3. Remove the old physical volume and discard the image

The problem I am having is with step 2: based on my knowledge, it will fail because there are fewer physical extents available on the new volume than are used on the old volume. I could move only a portion of the extents, but how do I know which ones actually contain the data? How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: I was able to get this working by following the guide https://dsavenko.me/migrating-centos-system-from-hdd-to-smaller-ssd-on-xfs-filesystem/. In short, create a new, separate disk and use xfsdump to move the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't shrink root volume online. Reducing the logical volume on the root file system must be done in **rescue mode**.

Centos 7 has a default filesystem of XFS which cannot be reduced in size. please refer the [link](https://xfs.org/index.php/Shrinking_Support).

I would suggest, convert this volume as thin provision volume if possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware you can't shrink XFS. That's why I came up with the procedure I suggested. However, if I can convert to a thin provisioned volume, that would work.